# When dealing with matrix exponentials, can we assume $e^{-A}=(e^A)^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-exponential

Of course, $e^{-x}=(e^x)^{-1}$, but in this case we have a matrix $A$. I think it is in fact true that $e^{-A}=(e^A)^{-1}$, but how would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because\begin{align}e^Ae^{-A}&=e^{A+(-A)}\text{ (since $A$ and $-A$ commute)}\\&=e^0\\&=\operatorname{Id}.\end{align}

Comment: Note: $e^Ae^B = e^{A+B}$ is not generally true, but is true when $A, B$ commute.